# Is it ok to share your trello developer API key?

Tags: api, api-key, trello

Is it ok to share your Trello developer API key that is generated at https://trello.com/1/appKey/generate? See the [documentation](https://trello.com/docs/gettingstarted/index.html#getting-an-application-key) for more details. I assume this key would be visible in any application you publish but I'd rather ask a stupid question than make stupid mistake.

Comment: uhhh no? sounds like a bad idea

Comment: ok, so I need to have them give my application their developer key and have them authorize and enter a token? Seems like asking a lot for a lot of steps.

Comment: it looks like that's what other projects are doing. fair enough. thanks for the advice!

Comment: I asked this same question of trello and this is the answer I got:The reason you may not want to share your API key is because we can throttle and block API usage per API key. If someone else where to abuse your API key, we could end up blocking you while trying to curb the malicious use of another user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consensus is you should not share your key. Here are a few examples of using the Trello API:

https://github.com/GraemeF/trello

https://gist.github.com/1893771

You'll need to have them provide their API key and a token.